# Python vs C++ for CUDA web server?

Tags: python, c++, cuda

I am planning on writing some software for a web server that uses machine learning to process large amounts of data. This will be real estate data from a MySQL server. I will be using the CUDA framework from Nvidia with python/caffe or the c++ library. I will be using a Tesla P100. Although python is more widely used for machine learning I presume it is hard to write a server app in python without sacrificing performance. Is this true? Is c++ well supported for machine learning? Will anything be sacrificed by writing a professional server app in python (ex: connecting to MySQL database)?

Comment: Most the Machine Learning libs are written in C/C++ with wrappers for python so there is any problem with perfomance. But, if you need to do a lot of processing outside the CUDA enviroment then python could be to slow.

Comment: You asked this same basic question a couple of hours and it was closed. That wasn't an accident

Comment: I was under the impression that the question was not specific enough so I rewrote it to make it more specific. If there is another issue with this post I would be happy to take that into consideration.

Comment: Machine learning and web server seems to me to be two separate concerns.

Comment: I apologize if this is unclear. My intent is to write a cloud app on a server with a GPU accelerator. The question at hand is whether I should do the machine learning on my flask app or if I should handle the learning and regression in c++ and then interface that with my flask app.

Comment: The problem with this question is that there is no answer. You are basically soliciting opinions. And that is explicitly off-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both C++ and Python are perfectly reasonable languages for implementing web servers. Python is actually quite common, and there are many frameworks for writing web servers in Python such as [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/), [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), etc. Architecturally, I wonder whether you really need the machine learning (which I imagine would be a data processing pipeline) and the web server to be the same process / binary; however, even if you do them in the same server, I suspect that either language would be perfectly reasonable; moreover, if you ever came to the point where you needed to run a piece of computation in C++ for performance, using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to call C++ from Python or using some form of message passing from Python to a C++ helper process (such as via [gRPC](http://www.grpc.io/)) are options.

Answer (score 1):

Python is a language that performs worse than c++ in terms of runtime for several reasons:

First and foremost, Python is a scripting language that runs with an interpreter as opposed to c++ which compiled into machine code before running.

Secondly: python runs in the background a garbage collector system while in c++ the memory management is done manually by the programmer.

**In your case, I recommend that you work with Python for several reasons:**

1. Writing in Python in CUDA allows you to compile the code even though it is Python (CUDA provides JIT - Just In Time compiler, as well as a compiler and other effective tools), Which greatly improves performance
2. Python provides many, rich varied libraries that will help you a lot in the project, especially in the field of machine learning.
3. The development time and code length will be significantly shorter in Python.

From my experience with working at CUDA in the Python language I recommend you use numba and numbapro libraries, they are comfortable to work with and provide support for many libraries like numpy.

Best of luck.